# Proving that $V$ is a vector space, if $a+b=ab$ and $a *b=a^b$.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I am currently studying Halmos' "Linear Algebra Problem Book" and am stuck on problem 21(4).

Let $V$ be the set $\mathbb{R}_+$, and let $F$ be the set $\mathbb{R}$.

Let's define the sum of two positive numbers: 
$$a+b = ab,$$
and the product of a positive number $a$ and a real number $b$: 
$$a*b = b^a.$$
Prove that $V$ is a vector-space.

Proving that addition is commutative, associative, as well as the existence of an additive identity (which is equal to $1$) and an inverse (which is equal to $1/x$) wasn't problematic.

However, multiplication and distributivity caused a few problems. Is the multiplicative identity also $1$, since $x^1 = x$?

Is $(ab) x = x^{b^a}$, in which case isn't $a (bx) = {x^b}^a = x^{ba}$?

Comment: Multiplicative identity? A vector space doesn't have one of those-that's for a ring.

Comment: You define scalar multiplication by "ab= a^b" but later you appear to be using "ab= b^a".  Which is it?

Comment: @KevinCarlson, what I meant is there is an identity for scalar multiplication.  See property 8 in http://mathworld.wolfram.com/VectorSpace.html.

Comment: It should be noted that $1$ - as in the element of the vector space - is the additive identity and $1$ - as in the element of the underlying field - is the multiplicative identity (of the underlying field). They have the same symbol, but they mean different things.

Comment: @user247327 Yes, sorry, it's the latter (ab=b^a).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, the scalar $1 \in \Bbb R$ is the multiplicative identity for the vector space, because $x^1=x$, as you wrote.

---

Actually, $(ab)x \neq x^{a^b}$ because since $a,b$ are scalars, their product is the usual multiplication on $\Bbb R$, not the scalar multiplication as defined for a scalar and a vector.

Hence, $(ab)x=x^{ab}=x^{ba}=(x^b)^a=a(x^b)=a(bx)$, so scalar multiplication is associative.

---

For distributivity, what you need is $(a+b)x=ax+bx$ and $a(x+y)=ax+yx$.

The first one: $(a+b)x=x^{a+b}=x^ax^b=ax+bx$

The second one: $a(x+y)=a(xy)=(xy)^a=x^ay^a=ax+ay$.

Comment: A side note: in general it is false that $x^{a^b}=x^{ab}$. To see this, take $x=2, a=2,b=3$. Then $x^{a^b}=2^{2^3}=2^8$, and $x^{ab}=2^{2\cdot 3}=2^6$.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't really understand how the operations were defined (I thought a+b meant ab).

Comment: You're welcome. In this example it's easy to mix the operations up!

Answer (score 2):

**Different approach:** note that
$$
a+_V b = \exp(\log(a) + \log(b))\\
a*_V b = \exp(b\cdot \log(a))
$$

Answer (score 1):

Distributivity is just $(ab)^c=a^cb^c$. Associativity (of the action) is $(a^b)^c=a^{bc}$.

$(ab)x=x^{ab}$, by the definition of the action. $a(b(x))$ is $(x^b)^a=x^{ba}$, which you should be careful to distinguish from $x^{b^a}$, since exponentiation is not associative.