# why and how does the set be a vector space?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, vector-spaces

Let $V$ be a set of **positive real numbers** with addition

$$ x + y = xy$$

and scalar multiplication

$$cx = x^c.$$

Show that $V$ is a vector space under addition and scalar multiplication.

My text book says it is a vector space but I do not understand why since I  am not able to find a zero vector in $V$.

Comment: The number $1$ is your additive identity (or, zero vector). This is because

$$x+1 = 1 \cdot x = x$$

Comment: This exercise trips a lot of people up. Since the proposed vector space is actually a subset of the field, it's important to differentiate between the operations. After all, it's difficult to tell from context whether $1 + 3 + 5$ refers to scalar addition (i.e. $9$), or whether it's vector addition (i.e. $1 \times 3 \times 5 = 15$). You should notate vector addition with a different symbol, e.g. $x\oplus y = xy$, and the same for scalar multiplication, e.g. $c \odot x = x^c$. If you rewrite the axioms with this notation, you might find it easier to prove them.

Comment: So $x+y=xy=y^x$?

Comment: No. It would be clearer to use alternative notation.

We want to see if the positive reals, equipped with the operations $\oplus,\odot$ below, are a vector space:

$$x \oplus y \stackrel{\text{def.}}{=} x \cdot y \qquad
x \odot y \stackrel{\text{def.}}{=} x^y$$

where multiplication and exponentiation are their "usual" operations.

Comment: Logarithm and exponential gives an isomorphism between that vector space and $\mathbb{R}$ with its usual vector space structure.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Proving that $V$ is a vector space, if $a+b=ab$ and $a *b=a^b$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1361445/proving-that-v-is-a-vector-space-if-ab-ab-and-a-b-ab)

Comment: this was helpful thank you