# How is vector addition of x + y = xy and scalar multiplication kx=x^k?

Tags: vector-spaces, vectors

New poster, so apologies if format is bad, but I am just getting started with the topic of vector spaces and it is very confusing to me.

One example in the textbook starts like below, but I can't for the life of me figure out how this is true. Maybe I am overcomplicating it. Can anyone ELI5? Thanks!

> Consider the set $V$ of positive real numbers. If $x$ and $y$ denote positive real numbers, then we write vectors in $V$ as $\vec{x} = x$ and $\vec{y} = y$. Now, addition of vectors is defined by $$ \vec{x} + \vec{y} = xy$$ and scalar multiplication is defined by $$ k \vec{x} = x^{k} $$

Comment: You have various properties of these operations to check. Go through the list one by one and verify. For starters, what is the zero vector?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Proving that $V$ is a vector space, if $a+b=ab$ and $a *b=a^b$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1361445/proving-that-v-is-a-vector-space-if-ab-ab-and-a-b-ab)

Comment: I think OP is maybe confused about, how do we prove $x+y=xy$? But this is a misapprehension. We (re)*define* the symbol $+$ to take two 'vectors' $x,y$ to their usual product $xy$. We are not claiming, say, $1+2=1\cdot2$ where both sides are usual arithmetic operations; we are *defining* $\mathrm{vector addition}(1,2):=1\cdot2$

Comment: I guess what I was mainly confused about is how can you say that x+y =xy, as FShrike was saying. Are we able to just define whatever we want? because I still don't understand how adding 2 vectors somehow is the same as multiplying their elements together..

Comment: I do not need help in determining if this is a vector space, I just want to know how we can prove what the author defined.

Answer (score 1):

You need only check that the axioms are satisfied. In particular, check that the vector space axioms are satisfied, and substitute out the vector addition and multiplication operators for their defined operations while doing so.

For example, using v to denote the vector space operation, we need to check that $k \cdot_{v} (x +_{v} y) = k \cdot_{v} x +_{v} k \cdot_v y$. By definition of the operations, this is equivalent to checking that $k \cdot_v (xy) = x^k +_v y^k$. But this is just akin to checking that $(xy)^k = x^ky^k$, and this is easy.

The rest should be straightfoward.

Comment: I think you meant to write $k \cdot_{v} x +_{v} k \cdot_{v} y$ rather than $k \cdot_{v} x +_{v}.$